# What do I call a set of datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, terminology

For training a Machine learning model,
I have 3 datasets:

- Training
- Validation
- Testing

Normally I obtain there by dividing up the full dataset into pieces. 
I've created a function in my code to return the 3 of them in a record (ie named tuple, ie structure)  an I need a name to refer to the grouping of the 3.

Currently I am using Learning_datasets,
but that isn't great.

Is there some kinda of commonly used phrase or term? 
Like a set of trees is called a forest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is not a specific name for this combination. You could name your function "[data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data)" (or just "dataset")  as it will return all the information available (train + validation + test).